# How to connect c# windows application with online access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2007

We are planning to develop an application for our college accounts Online(centralized). We have chosen C# for this task and Ms access 2007 database , and i would like to know,  how can we connect with Online access Database?

Comment: Any effort so far? Your 'question' is too broad

Comment: Flagged as Too Broad

Comment: Your question is not a specific one. Just start by creating an ASP.Net application in Visual Studio.

First write out the details you are going to store in MSAccess and write the code accordingly.

** Create tables in MS Access

** Create Forms to get those details

** pass the values to MS Access

Here you can read the basics --> ASP.Net C# with MS Access

Comment: sir, actually what i want is , how to set the connection string for access online "Access Database".

Comment: and finally, i got the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to "Setting up an Access Database for Your Hosting Account" for online availability of "Access Database" as a centralized.

If your hosting is with godaddy then visit this [Link](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/34/setting-up-an-access-database-for-your-hosting-account?countrysite=pk)

Here is a sample code of access online "Access Database"

```
string connectionString = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    @"Data Source="Path of you hosting provider database";" +
    @"User Id= "hosting db user id];Password=[hosting db password";";

string queryString = "SELECT Foo FROM Bar";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

for more visit this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8269/How-to-link-to-an-Access-Database-in-a-C-Applicati), hope this will help you.

Comment: You are most welcome to genius and helpful peoples of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search revealed that you use System.Data.OleDb, for referance, check out the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452.aspx

Please note that accessing remote databases directly from C# is bad practice, as you would have to obtain the credentials somehow, and your application could be reverse engineered and the credentials exposed, thus leaving your database wide open for your students to do whatever they please with.

What you would usually do is have the server take care of talking with the database, and simply request information from the server from the client. If the server is simply a windows box, the easiest thing to do would probably be to create a HTTP server using System.Net.HttpListener or you could alternatively use ASP if you already have that going. In both cases you would use System.Data.OleDb.

In the case that it is a Linux box, I would urge you to consider creating a MySQL database and use PHP, which is also common practice.

Comment: Bad practice to access a database? Seriously?

Comment: Note that I said "remote database". If it is local and you are not worried about the user manipulating the data it is fine; Skype for instance store conversations in a SQLlite database. It is also fine to access a database directly from C# in ASP as clients does not have access to the code.
Downloading the database from the server and then accessing it on the machine would be fine too, but do not, under any circumstances, access a remote database directly from C#.
Your program can be decompiled - which is quite trivial in C# actually -, which would leave your database wide open.

Comment: This is total nonsense. It has _always_ been trivial to reverse-engineer .NET code, in C#, VB.NET, or any other .NET language. That has never made it a bad practice to access a remote database using such code. I have no idea where you're getting this concept from, but if it's a bad idea today, then it was a bad idea 12 years ago when .NET was introduced.